# Short else in php code (Yii)

Tags: php, yii

I have some statemnt in yii cgridview

```
'value' => '($data->active==0)?"Не подтвержден":"Подтвержден"',
```

How i can do as `if(){}elseif(){}else{}`

Comment: Tip: Unless you are stuck with the ancient PHP 5.2, just create an anonymous function instead of stuffing the code into a string. It will be far more readable and less likely to confuse others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use this many times. and this is work greate

'value'=>'(expression)?"data":((expression)?"data2":"data3")'

In your example

'value' = '($data->active==0)?"Не подтвержден":(($data->active==1)? "statement2":"statement3")'

Answer (score 2):

Something like this

`'value' => 3 > 2 ? 'if' : (3 > 4 ? 'elseif' : 'else')`

Answer (score 1):

```
(ifstatement)?'value_if':((ifelsestatement)?'value_ifelse':'value_else')
```